# C++ Linker error when trying to include tiny obj loader header file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use [tiny_obj_loader](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) to load an `.obj` into my program. I have the following code utilising this library:

```
void LoadModel(vector<Shape *> &scene, const char *path) {
  attrib_t attrib;
  vector<shape_t> shapes;
  vector<material_t> materials;
  std::string error;
  bool ret = tinyobj::LoadObj(
    &attrib,
    &shapes,
    &materials,
    &error,
    path
  );
  ... // Do stuff with the returned data
```

This, however, gives me the following linker error:

```
Build/skeleton.o: In function `LoadModel(std::vector<Shape*, 
std::allocator<Shape*> >&, char const*)':
skeleton.cpp:(.text+0x3025): undefined reference to `tinyobj::LoadObj(tinyobj::attrib_t*, std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t, std::allocator<tinyobj::shape_t> >*, std::vector<tinyobj::material_t, std::allocator<tinyobj::material_t> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, char const*, bool)'
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'Build' failed
make: *** [Build] Error 1
```

Where the function  definition is:

```
bool LoadObj(attrib_t *attrib, std::vector<shape_t> *shapes,
         std::vector<material_t> *materials, std::string *err,
         const char *filename, const char *mtl_basedir = NULL,
         bool triangulate = true);
```

Which looks like the parameter types are correct to me.

I have included the `.h` file in `skeleton.cpp` with

```
#include "tiny_obj_loader.h"
```

`tiny_obj_loader.h` is the name of the file, which is in the same directory of `skeleton.cpp`.

**EDIT**
The Makefile being used is:

```
FILE=skeleton

########
#   Directories
S_DIR=Source
B_DIR=Build

########
#   Output
EXEC=$(B_DIR)/$(FILE)

# default build settings
CC_OPTS=-std=c++11 -c -pipe -Wall -Wno-switch -O3 -xHOST -qopenmp
LN_OPTS=-qopenmp
CC=icpc

########
#       SDL options
SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
GLM_CFLAGS := -I../glm/
SDL_LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl2-config --libs)

########
#   This is the default action
all:Build


########
#   Object list
#
OBJ = $(B_DIR)/$(FILE).o

########
#   Objects
$(B_DIR)/$(FILE).o : $(S_DIR)/$(FILE).cpp $(S_DIR)/SDLauxiliary.h $(S_DIR)/TestModelH.h $(S_DIR)/tiny_obj_loader.h
    $(CC) $(CC_OPTS) -o $(B_DIR)/$(FILE).o $(S_DIR)/$(FILE).cpp $(SDL_CFLAGS) $(GLM_CFLAGS)


########
#   Main build rule     
Build : $(OBJ) Makefile
    mkdir -p $(B_DIR) && $(CC) $(LN_OPTS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ) $(SDL_LDFLAGS)


clean:
    rm -f $(B_DIR)/*
```

Comment: No, I've included the Makefile I use as an edit to the original post.

Comment: Did you `#define TINYOBJLOADER_IMPLEMENTATION` in one (and only one) .cpp file?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in skeleton.cpp and nowhere else.

Comment: This might seem silly, but you did define it *before* including the file yes? Otherwise I have no clue.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you. If you write that as the answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to `#define TINYOBJLOADER_IMPLEMENTATION` before actually including `tiny_obj_loader.h`. Otherwise the preprocessor will have already run on that file and you won't get the implementation.